# Need compatible USB WiFi adapter for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, usb

The computer. 
Intel i5-4440 processor, Intel DB85FL motherboard on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

Please suggest me a WiFi USB adapter to work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of supported wifi adapters [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers)

I have very good experience with the *netgear wpn111*
and the *Conrad wlan stick n300 mini*.

Also almost all Intel adapters are supported.